# swift cornerRadius only bottom-left & top-right?

Tags: swift

swift corner radius problem

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:username.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
        username.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

[Output](http://image.prntscr.com/image/a814baf7ff8547428105eca192047959.png)

[I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30TrM.png)

Comment: What is `userName`, `UILabel`, `UITextField` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass the view that you'd like to give corners to, you can do it like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.topLeft.union(.topRight), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but has error
http://image.prntscr.com/image/28f4ab63a1424f4abaef3e36530df46f.png

Comment: Capitalize the T in top. They changed it for Swift 3 and you're still using 2